# Crafter CMS : Upload multiple images

Tags: java, crafter-cms

I use Rich text Editor for uploading images & I create 1 data source for uploading image. When I upload image it is not shown (broken image logo), while I am not publish this image.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The image is not shown because it cannot be severed for some reason.  There could be any number of reasons for this.  Here is how I would trouble shoot the issue:

1. upload an image via the RTE
2. Right click on the image, inspect element, look at the path to the image
3. it should say PROTOCOL://SERVER:PORT/static-assets/etc/etc/etc

If the URI doesn't start with static-assets then Crafter's download servlet cannot serve it.  You need to fix the path in your datasource.

If the path does start with static-assets then check and see if the image is in your repository at that path specified. You probably won't find it there.  If that's the case check your tomcat logs for an error.  If the error doesn't help you, post it here and we will go from there.